How do you define a landscape layout for the PreferenceScreen?
The Android PreferenceScreen layout is defined in the res/xml folder as root_preferences.xml.  How can I define a landscape version of this?  Normally, from my understanding, is that you would create a directory layout-land and put a same named version in there.  I tried this but it complained there was no regular version of the layout as I presume it looked in layout directory for root_preferences.xml and it wasn't there.
I also tried putting root_preferences.xml in layout directory but I couldn't build the project.   It couldn't resolve the Class PreferenceScreen and the "add dependancy" solution suggested did nothing.

You don't provide any landscape layout for preferences. If you want something more suited for a large, landscape screen, you'd use PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat. Is there a reason you're trying to provide a landscape layout at all?

"Is there a reason you're trying to provide a landscape layout at all?"  Android provides landscape layouts so the apps look nice in any orientation.  "More suited for a large landscape screen" doesn't make any sense.  Orientation changes and layouts are about the ratio of portrait vs landscape.

Portrait vs landscape hasn't been a recommended way to write Android apps for literally years - here's a blog from 8 years ago about how thinking in portrait vs landscape was already not the right way to approach building apps. It is about responsive breakpoints of bigger widths, which is exactly what PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat does for you.

You are misrepresenting the content of the blog post you linked.  It simply instructs on how to handle multi app windows and on orientation change.

Given that I wrote the blog post, I am very aware how it talks how portrait and landscape doesn't mean what you think it means and how it also specifically calls out responsive design which, if you were to read any of the other content linked from it, you would find also does not reference portrait or landscape at all, but responsive breakpoints, exactly like I said.

@ianhanniballake: I agree that PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat is the right direction. That said, and with all due respect, if Google wants developers using that, it would help if we had more to go on. The KDocs lack a fully-fleshed-out example and leave a lot to the imagination (what is PreferenceHeader? where does TwoPanePreference get referenced?). And nothing else significant has been written about it.


The Android PreferenceScreen layout is defined in the res/xml folder as root_preferences.xml.

Few developers would describe a preference XML resource as a "layout".

How can I define a landscape version of this?

Technically speaking, you would create res/xml-land/ and put the landscape resource there. That said, this is highly unlikely to give you what you want.

Android provides landscape layouts so the apps look nice in any orientation

Again, preference XML resources are not layouts. They are descriptions of preferences that you would like to have collected from the user. How the UI is rendered, especially at the screen level, is determined by the code that reads in the preference XML resource, not by the resource itself.

Orientation changes and layouts are about the ratio of portrait vs landscape.

While technically true, that reflects very old Android design thinking. As Ian Lake points out in the comments on your question, Android design now better follows its Web design predecessor, focusing on available width rather than aspect ratio. For example, the determination of whether to use two panes (e.g., list and detail) for some screen is not "is the screen wider than it is tall" and more "is the screen wide enough to warrant two panes".
If you do not like the "out of the box" behavior of preference screens, you need to focus on your Java or Kotlin code, not on the preference XML. The preference XML should remain the same whether the device is in held in portrait, held in landscape, held on some diagonal, or has a square or round screen. As Ian points out, you could use PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat to use a single pane on narrow screens and two panes on wider screens, though PreferenceHeaderFragmentCompat has limited documentation and may require some experimentation. It looks like SupportPreferenceDemos may show how it is used.
